# WIFI win login - "there are no logon servers available to service this request"

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, login, authentication

why does "there are no logon servers available to service this request" pop up when trying to log into windows via wifi after the account password was changed in AD?

Of course when I plug it into the network using a cable it will authenticate and afterwards it works via wifi without a problem.

I´m trying to make sense out of this - what´s the logic behind this "issue"?

cheers

Comment: After you successfully log on, can you confirm that the wifi is actually able to connect to your authentication server?

Comment: Go to device manager to see if "turn off this device to save power" is enabled on the WiFi adaptor. Or try to untick ipv6 on wifi network adaptor.

Comment: @Vylix - My first guess would be Yes - if after the first log (after the password change) using a network cable I log off and try to log back on using the old password the authentication will fail.

Comment: @LukaKomarcic did you mean "new password" instead of "old password"? If the password has already been changed, it doesn't make sense to enter old password.